# How to mount an AWS EFS volume using Chef nfs cookbook

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra

It took me some trial and error to figure out how to convert the AWS EFS mount command to using a chef resource instead so I thought I wanted to share.

command given by amazon:

```
sudo mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2 $(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone).fs-01234567.efs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:/ efs
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
include_recipe 'nfs'

az = node['ec2']['placement_availability_zone']
region = az[0..-2] # trim last char
file_system_id = 'fs-01234567'
efs_uri = "#{az}.#{file_system_id}.efs.#{region}.amazonaws.com:/" 

directory '/mnt/efs' do
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '0755
  recursive true
  action :create
end

mount '/mnt/efs' do
  device efs_uri
  fstype 'nfs4'
  options 'nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2'
  action [:mount, :enable]
end
```

Comment: It looks like recently they made cross-AZ DNS names work per http://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/mounting-fs-mount-cmd-dns-name.html . So slightly refactoring the code above to `efs_uri = "{file_system_id}.efs.#{region}.amazonaws.com:/" ` should work.